# Installing Google Play Services 4.1 on Emulator

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Hi I'm trying to work with the new version of Google Play services (4.1) and am not able to get it working on my emulator. The Emulator loading with Google APIs level 19 only contain Google play services 4.0. How do i update this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version is 4.5.10 at the moment.

a)      You cam download t and then:

b)  Go to platform tools path present in Android SDK and put these apk's in it.

•   com.android.vending-4.5.10.apk

c)  Install these apk's one by one by going to platform tools path by using command prompt(shift+Right click---> open command window here).Then,Follow these commands

•adb devices

•adb install com.android.vending-4.5.10.apk

Comment: It doesnt allow me to install saying I already have it, but it is nowhere to be found on the emulator. Can i just download google paly services directly or does it have to be through the store

Comment: Figured it out. Had to install the google play services apk using the same process after this. Thank you!

Comment: You download it through the command prompt. (mode details: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUsBOZ7-qBE from minute 31:00)

Answer (score -3):

Try this,

> right click on your project > Android Tools > Add Support Library...

Comment: The support library *is not* Google Play Services.